# Jena: How to explicitly specify Accept Header sent by RDFDataMgr.loadModel(url)?

Tags: java, http-headers, rdf, jena

We need to query a server with a buggy Http Content Negotiation (it does not understand the q parameter in the Accept Header). So we would need to send the query with

`Accept:application/rdf+xml`

instead of Jena's default

`Accept: text/turtle,application/n-triples;q=0.9,application/rdf+xml;q=0.7,application/trig,application/n-quads;q=0.9,text/x-nquads;q=0.8,application/x-trig;q=0.7,application/ld+json;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5`

Here's the Java Code we currently use to set up Jena's Http handling:

```
static {
    HttpOp.setDefaultHttpClient(createHttpClient(1000, 4000));
}

protected static HttpClient createHttpClient(final int connectTimeout, final int readTimeout) {
        final RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout)
                .setSocketTimeout(readTimeout)
                .setContentCompressionEnabled(true)
                .setRedirectsEnabled(true)
                .build();

        final HttpHost gndHost = new HttpHost("host.net", 80);
        final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connMgr = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connMgr.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10);
        connMgr.setMaxTotal(50);
        connMgr.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(gndHost), 2);

        return HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setConnectionManager(connMgr)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .build();
    }
```

Can this general setup be altered, so that HttpQuery.setAccept("application/rdf+xml") is used for all requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService` returns a `QueryExecution` object which is in fact a `QueryEngineHTTP`, and that has `set*ContentType` methods.

If you want to get into really detailed control, you can use `HttpOp` directly with a `HttpResponseHandler` that passes the input stream to `RDFDataMgr`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andy. The second way is the right one for me as I am just resolving URIs, no SPARQL.

Answer (score 2):

This code does the job:

```
private Model fetchRemoteData(final String uri, final Boolean ignoreErrors) throws HttpException, TitleDataInvalidException {
        try {
            final Model rdfModel;
            if (uri.startsWith("http://d-nb.info")) {
                final Model tmpModel = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
                final TypedInputStream is = HttpOp.execHttpGet(uri, "application/rdf+xml");
                tmpModel.read(is, null);
                rdfModel = tmpModel;
            } else {
                rdfModel = RDFDataMgr.loadModel(uri);
            }
            return rdfModel;
        } catch (RiotException ex) {
    ...
```